# When exactly is the view-count incremented?

Tags: discussion

Curious: When I create a question I see a "views" of 1. Does that mean someone else has seen my question as soon as I have posted it?

When I refresh a question repeatedly, I sometimes see the view-count bump up. Does that mean there is new content in the question and/or someone else has viewed the question in that time?

Comment: for every unique visitor as far as I've been able to deduce over time :)

Comment: See [How are the number of views in a question calculated?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/36728/164403) on the Overmeta.

Answer (score 6):

> When I create a question I see a "views" of 1. Does that mean someone else has seen my question as soon as I have posted it?

The counter starts from **1**. So you may consider that you are counted as the first visitor of your own question.

> When I refresh a question repeatedly, I sometimes see the view-count bump up. Does that mean there is new content in the question and/or someone else has viewed the question in that time?

It means another user has viewed the question in the meanwhile. Editing of a question has no relation with *view count*. It is simply a count of unique visitors based on a particular time duration, visited IP address, and possibly some other factors.