# Will views on answers now be worth the same as views on questions?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, badges, views

This is related to recent [Upvotes on questions will now be worth the same as upvotes on answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/391250/upvotes-on-questions-will-now-be-worth-the-same-as-upvotes-on-answers?cb=1) discussion.

When we're at it, how come that only questions are rewarded with *view* points, but answers are not?

For example:

- notable question badge - question with 2.500 views
- famous question badge - question with 10.000 views

I guess that page visitors don't read only questions, but answers as well.

Do you plan to retroactively award all answers with "view" points and create additional badges, such as

- notable answer badge - answer with 2.500 views
- famous answer badge - answer with 10.000 views

How would you know whether someone actually read the answer? No idea; I presume the same way you know that someone read the question.

Comment: "How would you know whether someone actually read the answer?" The site doesn't keep track of anything quite so sophisticated in the view count. It's just how many times [the page has been loaded by unique visitors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/278316/7795130), and even then it's kind of lazy at keeping track of who's unique. Since answers are on the same page as a question, the view count is already also the answer view count, minus the few views from between when the question and answer were each posted. This doesn't seem like a useful feature, and would be complicated to implement.

Comment: Answer views are already rewarded in the awesome *people reached* statistic on your profile ...

Comment: Well you could know that someone read an answer by making the web page send his scroll bar position info to stack overflow servers. That way, with some calculations, you could know if the user scrolled down enough to make an answer visible.

Answer (score 4):

View history isn't tracked.

This means that a massively viewed question that get a new answer after gathering up views for 5 years, immediately rewards that answer with the proposed badge.

That aside, there is no way to determine a answer was actually viewed.

A page is loaded because of the question it contains. The question is always viewed.
A bad answer to that question is likely not to be viewed.

Answer (score 1):

View history is only tracked for the question, it would require changes to the site which I imagine SO wouldn't be interested in. With the current system being based on the question views there would be no way to stop someone posting an answer on a highly viewed question to simply farm badges, let us not have that.